# Retain Radio button selection on previous and next page in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, vue.js

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0]
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'style.css';
    links.appendChild(link);
    Vue.component('blog-post', {
        props: ["ques"],
        template:
        `<div class="content"  style="background-color: #ddd">
     <div v-for="items in ques" :key="items.id">
     <div :id="items.id">
     <label v-for="opt in items.options" :key="opt.id">
        <span class="round"</span>    
        <input type="radio" :name="items.name" :value="opt.score" :title="opt.text" 
    :checked="opt.isSelected" @change="$root.clickradio($event)" :disabled="false"/>{{ opt.text }}
        </label>
        <label class="quesname" v-text="items.desc"></label>
     </div>
        </div>
        </div>`
    });
    dispQues = []
    allposts = quesBank.length
    total_length = quesBank.length/2
    console.log(total_length)
    for(var q in quesBank){
        dispQues.push(quesBank[q])   
    }
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            dispQues:dispQues,
            limit:2,
            skip:0,
            currentpage:1,
            checked:"",
        },
    methods: {
        clickradio(){
            var total=0
            $(":radio:checked").each(function(){
                val1 = this.value
                name = this.name
                console.log(name)
                // this.checked = true
             total += Number(val1);
            console.log(total)
            // })
            });  
        },
        
        next: function () {
            if (!$(":radio").is(':checked')) {
                alert('Please answer the questions!');
            }
            else if ($('input:radio:checked').length <this.limit){
                    alert('answer all ques')
                }
            else if(this.currentpage<total_length){
                this.skip += this.limit
                this.currentpage++
            }
        },
        // Go to previous question
        prev: function (){
            if (this.currentpage>1){
            this.skip -= this.limit
            this.currentpage--
            }
        }
    },
      computed:{
        page(){
          return this.dispQues.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.limit)
        },
        isPreviousButtonDisabled() {
            return this.currentpage === 1
        },
        isNextButtonDisabled() {
            return this.currentpage === total_length
        },
       }
    })
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Vue Basics Example</title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app" style="width: 850px">
      <div>
        <label> Answer to Questions!! </label>
      </div>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 850px; margin: 0 auto">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            
              <blog-post :ques="page"></blog-post>
          
            </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <button v-on:click="prev" :disabled='isPreviousButtonDisabled'>Prev</button>
    <p>{{ skip }}</p>
    <p>{{ currentpage }}</p>
    <button @click="next" :disabled="isNextButtonDisabled">Next</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="questionsbackup.js"></script>
    <script src="./index0309.js"></script>
    </html>
```

I am new to Java script and using Vue.js for my application.
I am building a survey based application.
I am facing issues in retaining radio button selection in previous/next page.
I do not intend to use local storage.
I am trying to update the JSON checked status to true but when i click on next/previous button it is not reflecting.

JSON

```
var optionsBP= [
{
    id:1,
    score:0,
    text:'Strongly Dislike',
    isSelected:false
},
{
    id:2,
    score:1,
    text:'Dislike',
    isSelected:false
},
{
    id:3,
    score:2,
    text:'Unsure',
    isSelected:false
},
{
    id:4,
    score:3,
    text:'Like',
    isSelected:false
},
{
    id:5,
    score:4,
    text:'Strongly Like',
    isSelected:false
}
];
quesBank = [
{
    id:1,
    desc:'Build Kitchen Cabinets',
    options: optionsBP,
    name: 'res1',
    checked: 'false',
    selvalue: -1
},
{
    id:2,
    desc:'Lay Brock Or Tile',
    options: optionsBP,
    checked: 'false',
    name: 'res2',
    selvalue: -1
},
{
    id:3,
    desc:'Brick Tile3',
    options: optionsBP,
    name: 'res3',
    checked: 'false',
    selvalue: -1
},
{
    id:4,
    desc:'Brick Tile4',
    options: optionsBP,
    name: 'res4',
    checked: 'false',
    selvalue: -1
},
{
    id:5,
    desc:'Brick Tile5',
    options: optionsBP,
    name: 'res5',
    checked: false,
    selvalue: -1
},
{
    id:6,
    desc:'Brick Tile6',
    options: optionsBP,
    name: 'res6',
    checked: false,
    selvalue: -1
}
];
```